# How to make recursive a nested map function that takes info from different arrays JS

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, array, recursion

I am making an inventory application and I must create a function that allows me to perform different operations with the arrays that I have created, the application consumes data from an api and processes this data to modify some things, I found a way to do it but I don't consider it the most suitable because I have several nested map functions.

```js
const BUNDLE_VARIANTS = [
  {
    handle: "coffret-fleur-doranger",
    shopify_id: "6721591541967",
    variants:[
      {
        handle: "gel-douche-fleur-doranger",
        id: "6718544773327",
        qty: 4,
      },
      {
        handle: "bouteille-rechargeable-ju",
        id: "6701646184655",
        qty: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    handle: "coffret-lavant-mains-fleur-de-coton",
    shopify_id: "6944659964111",
    variants:[
      {
        handle: "copie-de-lavant-mains-fleur-de-coton",
        id: "6944659964111",
        qty: 4,
      },
      {
        handle: "bouteille-rechargeable-ju",
        id: "6701646184655",
        qty: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
];

let line_items = [
    {shopify_variant_id: 6944659964111, quantity: 2,},
];

let items = [
    {id: "6944659964111", qty: 1000, inventoryItem: 2325},
  {id: "6701646184655", qty: 1000, inventoryItem: 5656},
];

 for (const line_item of line_items) {
   const { shopify_variant_id: variantId, quantity } = line_item;

   BUNDLE_VARIANTS.map((variant)=>{
     if (variant.shopify_id.includes(variantId + "")) {
       variant.variants.map(
         (v)=>{
           let qtyToSubstract = v.qty*quantity;
           items.map((item)=>{ 
             if (v.id == item.id) {
               item.newQty = (item.qty-qtyToSubstract)
             } 
           });
         }
       )};
   });
 };
 
  console.log(items);
```

I hope you can help me to find a more suitable and efficient solution to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't explained anywhere the functionality of each of your arrays (`BUNDLE_VARIANTS`, `line_items` and `items`);  or even the purpose of your code. It's impossible to guess exactly what you are looking for!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MisterJojo https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask